# Handling touch events in multi threaded environment

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I am new to Blackberry playbook native development, I feel some difference(in handling touch events) with existing platform like android, iPhone and nokia, in existing platforms we just register a callback with an event and callback got called as soon as there is some event and all that stuff is parallel where as in blackberry you have to query device if there is some event present or not and this is somewhat serialized and due to this users has to experience some delays for their  input to work.
So to handle this scenerio I have decided to create a thread and in thread routine there would be an infinite loop that will keep on querying device and as soon there is some event available code will handle this.

Now I have two questions
1. Is this is the best way we can handle this scenerio, If No how could I efficiently handle this kind of scenerio.
2. If this method is right to cater this kind of scenerio then I am having trouble in getting screen events in child thread, I have created screen context, init egl and requested screen events in parent/main thread.

Please guide me
Regards
Ahsan